# How to clear the GLSurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

I'm using GLSurfaceView with video stream. Everything goes well. But when stream ends there is remaining picture in GLSurfaceView. How can I remove the picture from GLSurfaceView ?

BTW when I jump to antoher activity and back, the remaing picture is gone.

------------------Updated-----------------------

I solved my problem with this:
    GLSurfaceView.setVisiblility(View.Invisible);
    GLSurfaceView.setVisiblility(View.Visible);
so GLSurfaceView can redraw itslef;

Expecting for a better answer.

Comment: I solved my problem with this:

Answer (score 0):

Try to call requestRender() after the video stream is ended.

Answer (score 0):

Try this magic code:

```
    view.setRenderer(new Renderer() {

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            // here are Red, Green, Blue and Alpha values between 0 and 1
            GLES20.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1); 
            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);                
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem, when switching source (and video component), but surface still shows old frame, but I need black screen.

What worked for me, all actions are done in the renderer (impl. `GLSurfaceView.Renderer`) class:

1. create `AtomicBoolean`, initial value is `false` (aka. `stopRendering` in example);
2. function for clearing surface (via OpenGL):

```
 private void clearSurface() {
     GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
     GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
 }
```

3. Then function to clear and stop rendering (I'm invoking it when switching `VideoComponent` of player):

```
 public void clearAndStopRendering() {
     stopRendering.set(true);
     glSurface.requestRender();
 }
```

4. Resume frame rendering when frame is ready:

```
    @Override
   public void onVideoFrameAboutToBeRendered(long presentationTimeUs, long releaseTimeNs, @NonNull Format format, @Nullable MediaFormat mediaFormat) {
       if (stopRendering.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
           glSurface.requestRender();
       }
   }
```

How my `onDrawFrame` looks like:

```
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // some initialization code, related to my work      

        if (stopRendering.get()) {
            clearSurface();
            return;
        }

        // Drawing ...
    }
```

My code in the `GLSurfaceView`, where I'm triggering clearing:

```
    public void setVideoComponent(@Nullable Player.VideoComponent newVideoComponent) {
        if (newVideoComponent == videoComponent) {
            return;
        }
        if (videoComponent != null) {
            // clearing old VideoComponent
            renderer.clearAndStopRendering();
        }
        videoComponent = newVideoComponent;
        // setup new VideoComponent 
    }
```

So, what I'm achieved: every time when `VideoComponent` changing (via custom `PlayerView` which includes my `GLSurfaceView`), black screen rendered and then, after video frame is ready, renders it, instead of the old frame.

**P.S.** BTW second variant, if you are using custom `PlayerView` as I'm, you could just do:

```
class MyGlPlayerView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null
) : PlayerView(context, attrs), MyPlayerView {

    private lateinit var glSurfaceView: MyGLSurfaceView

    override fun onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate()

        val contentFrame = findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.exo_content_frame)

        glSurfaceView = MyGLSurfaceView(context, false);

        contentFrame.addView(glSurfaceView, 0)
        setShutterBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)
    }

    override fun setPlayer(player: Player?) {
        glSurfaceView.setVideoComponent(player?.videoComponent)

        super.setPlayer(player)
    }
```